# How to add new web project to ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: module, aspnetboilerplate

I have followed [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/princeppy/ae0f24417f6ccdc7ccc73587ed9f1769) to create a modular application (`JPY-D360`) based on ASP.NET Zero module (`JPY-Zero`). But this tutorial didn't guide me to add a new web Area to new web project module (`JPY.D360.Web`). So that I have to create a new area in the core module (`JPY.Zero.Web`).

My current structure

[image]

--> My project `JPY.D360.Web` is useless and the instruction goes wrong. Could anyone guide me how to create a new area in the new web project `JPY.D360.Web` ?

Comment: is it Aspnet Zero or Aspnetboilerplate?

Comment: Aspnet Zero, bro

Comment: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewforum.php?f=5